# centering a google map based on marker lat long values

Tags: google-maps

I'm plotting about 20 markers on a map, locations in a city. When I use getLatLng to find the city center it's always a little removed from the locations I'm plotting, which means the markers are usually located in a corner of my map instead of in the center.

is there a way to center the map on a location that is more central to my locations? I'm guessing I need some sort of "average" lat / long coordinate calculated from the 20 lat / long values I have available.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finding the center should be pretty easy. Just find the smallest and largest latitude and longitude coordinates in your group of 20.

The center will be `[min_lat + (max_lat - min_lat)/2, min_long + (max_long - min_long)/2]`.

Something like:

```
var points = Array(); 
points.push(new GLatLng( xxx, yyy )); 
...

min_lat = 90;
max_lat = -90;
min_long = 180; 
max_long = -180; 
for (p in points) {
    if (p[0] < min_lat) {
        min_lat = p[0];
    }
    if (p[0] > max_lat) { 
        max_lat = p[0];
    }
    if (p[1] < min_long) {
        min_long = p[1];
    }
    if (p[1] > max_long) { 
        max_long = p[1];
    }
}

center = new GLatLng(min_lat + (max_lat - min_lat) / 2, 
                     min_long + (max_long - min_long) / 2];
map.setCenter(center, 10);
```

This code will probably have trouble if your points cross the longitude boundaries (±180°). It's also assuming that the points are located on a flat surface (rather than the surface of a sphere).

None of that should matter much if you're talking about coordinates within several hundred miles of each other in the US.